# JavaScript hex2bin implementation

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to implement a JS analogue of PHP's `hex2bin`. I found a few versions of hex2bin in JS, but all of these show the same result, which is different from the PHP result.

For example, a string `440EF96DB9A2225C32E031659DF2608B49932F0D8AFAC46F74FA56FF3E1AE952` looks like this:

[image]

As I can see, the results are **very** similar, but still different. What can be wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the textual representation of binary data.

Comment: @tkausl Yes, you're right, but even md5 of these results give a different values.

Comment: How do you hash them?

Comment: With a standard function in PHP, and with a custom implementation of md5 in JS. But! Both of functions give the same result if I hash any string, for example.

Comment: Perhaps a problem with JS md5? Something wrong with hash of binary data?

Comment: Can you post some source code? I assume you're not hashing it correct in javascript. PHP's strings are binary safe and most functions work on binary data, in javascript you need to be careful to not treat the data as string of characters.

Comment: I'm use this JS implementation of md5 (since it supports a raw binary format output, like in PHP): https://github.com/satazor/js-spark-md5/blob/master/spark-md5.js

Comment: Also you may take a look to full source code of my efforts: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3auapo59ubclph/test.php?dl=0

Comment: You should use `SparkMD5.hashBinary` for binary data. I'm getting `4030eb667aa1edcb48ff49355c8dc549` as hash in both PHP and JavaScript for `440EF96DB9A2225C32E031659DF2608B49932F0D8AFAC46F74FA56FF3E1AE952` -> hex2bin -> md5.

Comment: @tkausl , great, it works! Thank you so much for advise!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong. The results are the same, but strings are visualised differently. PHP and JavaScript output certain characters differently. Take for instance the character with code point 249:

```
echo chr(249);
// Equivalent to 
echo hex2bin("F9");
```

The output is "�".

While in JavaScript the output of the same character is "ù":

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(249));
```

Other characters may not be visible at all in one, but visible in the other. Both languages differ in internal character encoding which may also play a role in their rendering of strings.

If you want to ensure that they are the same, then represent the `hex2bin` output in base64 encoding:

In PHP ([`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)):

```
base64_encode(hex2bin("440EF96DB9A2225C32E031659DF2608B49932F0D8AFAC46F74FA56FF3E1AE952"));
```

In JavaScript ([`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa)):

```js
const hex2bin = s => s.match(/../g).map(c => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c, 16))).join``;

console.log(btoa(hex2bin("440EF96DB9A2225C32E031659DF2608B49932F0D8AFAC46F74FA56FF3E1AE952")));
```

Both output:

> RA75bbmiIlwy4DFlnfJgi0mTLw2K+sRvdPpW/z4a6VI=